# PDO::PARAM vs Filter Sanitize

Tags: php, filter, pdo

Can someone confirm this: If I am using PDO::PARAM, I don't need to Filter sanitize to inject into mysql database, since PDO:PARAM already does it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "PDO::PARAM" I suppose you mean [*binding parameters*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) into prepared statements.

Yes, if you properly use prepared statements, you do not need to do anything more to avoid SQL injection, because the database has a chance to clearly see the difference between the SQL statement and the user-supplied values. Binding parameters does not sanitize or escape those values, it sidesteps the whole business of sanitizing and escaping by separating statements from data.